# Удаленный DISPLAY и DBUS (QDBUS)

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, bash, shell

Суть вопроса:

Имеется две программы(P1 и P2), написанные с использованием DBUS (обмениваются сообщениями во время работы), имеются два ПК: на одном собственно эти программы запускаются, на втором происходит отображение gui запущенного софта.

Запуск: 
P1 запускает не хитрый скрипт с помощью такой строки:

```
DISPLAY=192.168.0.75:0.0 /usr/mysoft/prog1&
```

После чего P1 успешно запускается и рисует свое окно на 192.168.0.75, далее запускается Р2, с которой должно вестись взаимодействие по DBUS(консольная). Увы ничего не происходит.

Может кто-то знает как победить этого зверя?

Читал в гугл про DISPLAY=:0.0 и $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, но так пока и не понял как применить в моем случае....

Comment: Если запустить приложения на машине без DISPLAY=192.168.0.75:0.0 /usr/mysoft/prog1&, то DBUS работает корректно.

Comment: D-Bus не умеет по сети, только через локальные сокеты (unix domain sockets).